# Error using mysql in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, mysql, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

I have created an AWS Lambda function to retrieve info from an AWS RDS Database. I have also created an API in AWS API Gateway that triggers the Lambda function. The API works fine when my SQL statement is "select * from user". However, when I try something like "select * from user with tag = people", I get this error:

```html
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tag = 'people'' at line 1","trace":["Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tag = 'people'' at line 1","    at PromisePool.query (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:330:22)","    at Runtime.module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:19:38)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}
```

My AWS Lambda function defined as (Node.js 12.x):

```html
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.LAMBDA_HOSTNAME,
    user: process.env.LAMBDA_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.LAMBDA_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.LAMBDA_DATABASE,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
});

module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyLoop = false;
    const tag = event["params"]["querystring"]["tag"]
    const sql = "select * from user with tag = " + tag;

    const promisePool = pool.promise();
    const [rows] = await promisePool.query(sql);
    const lambdaProxyResponse = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify([rows])
    };
    return lambdaProxyResponse;
};
```

Can someone help me out with this issue? Also when I run the command in mysql workbench, it executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive what your overall environment looks like but first and foremost it's not a great idea to compose your own SQL this way.  This code could potentially be subject to a SQL injection attack.

But, assuming you trust the input, it's a pretty simple fix.  You need quotes:

```
const sql = "select * from user with tag = '" + tag + "'";
```

Note that this is true when the column is a string type.  On an numeric type you would not need the quotes.

If you *don't* trust the input then you need to look at using prepared statements of some sort.